# Почему появляется ошибка Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

При стартовом запуске проекта, когда проходит тестовое построение проекта у меня появляется ошибка, хотя раньше ее не было. Что делать и как решить?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

Comment: Так там же написано что версии api разные, в gradle проверить все ли нормально

Comment: а как его вообще проверить?? тип в директорию идти в проводнике или в студие где-то посмотреть?

Comment: в студии в разделе gradle scripts

Comment: build.gradle (Module app)

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло